# How can I prevent a SwiftUI view from being clipped to the bounds of its parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

How can I prevent a SwiftUI view from being clipped to the bounds of its window (or Scene)?

For instance, the code below initially displays a tiny blue circle:

[image]

After receiving a click, the circle's frame becomes bigger than its parent, and this is what's displayed:

[image]

How could I make it display the big blue circle, without modifying `InternalView`'s frame?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        InternalView()
            .frame(width: 10, height: 20)
    }
}

struct InternalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ZStack`? -- [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack)

Comment: ZStack doesn't seem to help here

Comment: do you want the window to resize automatically based the content size?

Comment: @ChrisR yes! on macOS it doesn't do so.

Answer (score 1):

like this???

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle().fill(.blue)
        .frame(width: size, height: size)
        .onTapGesture {
            size = 250 - size
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: no can do, because `InternalView` doesn't have access to `ContentView`'s `size`, because it's deep down in the view hierarchy.

Comment: could you pass the size up with `preferenceKey`?

Comment: May be use a Geometry reader ?

Comment: Haven't managed to get this working with `preferenceKey`, would appreciate some pointers :-)